# Have any Hamas officials ever opined in regard to Gaza-Sinai State (aka "Greater Gaza") proposal?

Tags: israel, palestine, gaza, hamas, egypt

[According to Al-Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/features/2017/7/24/is-gaza-sinai-state-a-possibility-for-palestinians) in 2017 Israel and the Trump administration worked on a deal that would see an establishment of a Palestinian state in Gaza and parts of Northern Sinai (possibly exceeding the size of Gaza as much as five-fold.) The Egypt was supposed to be seduced by financial incentives and a transfer of a part of the Israeli territory that would allow, e.g., construction of a direct path from Egypt to Jordan. Hamas was supposed to be seduced by becoming the government of the new state (even if under a nominal PA figurehead, like Mohammed Dahlan.)

The plan was apparently sufficiently serious to warrant a condemnation by the Palestinian Authority (which would be left out of the deal), and disclaimers from Egypt which didn't want to be seen as complotting with Israel.

2017 also falls into the period of some détente between Hamas and Israel, as [Hamas softened its charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Hamas_charter) - removing direct references to genocide of Jews (although still calling for wiping out Israel), whereas [Netanyahu administration also allowed Qatari funding of Hamas](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/12/11/middleeast/qatar-hamas-funds-israel-backing-intl/index.html).

I wonder if any Hamas officials/leaders have commented on this plan. On one hand, Hamas has always claimed that they are never going to give up Palestinian rights to any part of the Palestinian land (by which they mean the territory including Israel)... but on the other hand, getting their own official state seems like a very attractive prize... and no need to say that it would have been a real relief for the Gazans, suffering from overcrowding. (The deal likely would have meant displacement of some Sinai Bedouins - something that Egypt usually gets away with without much notice.)

Related:
[Sinai as an alternative to Gaza: Who is funding this? Who is passing the deal?](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20231025-sinai-as-an-alternative-to-gaza-who-is-funding-this-who-is-passing-the-deal/)
[A Palestinian State in North Sinai?](https://rosaluxna.org/publications/a-palestinian-state-in-north-sinai/)

Comment: There's a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_peace_plan) on Trump's peace plan but it doesn't mention plans for the Sinai except to say that Trump's negotiator Jason Greenblatt denied the plan would include a Palestinian state in the Sinai. So I'm guessing that while this had been briefly suggested, it was never a serious plan.

Comment: @StuartF my understanding is that the US officially never said anything about Sinai, but it was certainly involved.

Comment: Egypt is extremely unlikely to cede parts of its lands. Egypt-Jordan land bridge is highly impossible.

Comment: @alamar that might be the case. The question is whether Hamas expressed their opinion about this project - after all, the PA and Egypt found it necessary to do so, however hypothetical the project was.

Comment: Who downvote these legitimate questions?

Answer (score -2):

"Hamas officials" never opined about such a proposal AFAIK, but it doesn't really matter.

Hamas has nothing to do with any such proposal, as hypothetical as it might be. Their goal, as you referenced in your question, is the [annihilation of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Hamas_charter#Paragraphs_1%E2%80%9342) through various means. As such their opinion of any peace proposal is irrelevant because it would be inherently negative. Peace between Israel and the Palestinians goes contrary to the Hamas charter of not accepting Israel as an entity. You can't make peace with someone you claim has no right to exist.

The Palestinian Authority (the government of the West Bank) came out against any such proposal since they're trying to tie Gaza and the West Bank together, as they have always been ([The Oslo accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords) started with [Gaza and Jericho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza%E2%80%93Jericho_Agreement), and not just Gaza as the Israelis wanted, because of that). However, this is their internal political interest, they also have little to nothing to actually do about Gaza.

As the reality goes, there's not going to be any peaceful resolution with Gaza until either Hamas is removed from controlling it and someone more pro-Palestinian replaces them, or (more likely) it is re-occupied by Egypt.